# Preventing double booking

Tags: sql, database, oracle, locking

Lets say if I have the following:

```
create table jobs
(
  staff_id number,
  job_name varchar2(1000) not null,
  start_date date not null,
  end_date date not null
);
```

Which is just a table listing various jobs of staff.

Now staff can only do one job at a time, so I insert jobs using the following PL/SQL statement. If a clashing job is found, no job is added (I should probably report an error here, but for this simplified example I'm ignoring that):

```
create or replace procedure add_job
(
  p_staff_id number, 
  p_job_name varchar2, 
  p_start_date date, 
  p_end_date date
) 
as
begin
  insert into jobs 
  (
    select p_staff_id, p_job_name, p_start_date, p_end_date from dual 
    where not exists
    (
      select 1 from jobs 
      where staff_id = p_staff_id
        and (end_date > p_start_date)
        and (start_date < p_end_date)
    )
  );
end;
```

The problem is that if I add two different jobs in two different sessions, and then commit, I can double bookings. i.e the following:

```
-- Session 1:
add_job(1, 'Help Alice', to_date('2011/08/21 11:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24/MI/SS'), to_date('2011/08/21 13:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24/MI/SS'));

-- Session 2:
add_job(1, 'Help Bob',   to_date('2011/08/21 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24/MI/SS'), to_date('2011/08/21 14:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24/MI/SS'));

-- Session 1:
commit;

-- Session 2:
commit;
```

Above, `staff_id` 1 will be double booked between 12:00 and 13:00.

It seems that adding to the start of my procedure:

```
lock table jobs in exclusive mode;
```

did the trick, I feel like that's too broad a lock. Is there any way to coerce oracle into doing something a bit more finer grained. I'd rather not muck around with `dbms_lock` if possible. This [page](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-locking.html) hinted `select ... for update` would do the trick, but it didn't give details.

Is there any way to stop the double booking from occurring without a full table lock or `dbms_lock` lock? (I'm using Oracle 10g if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 2):

You obviously need a lock to prevent double bookings. Since you need to lock a specific staff member, my advice is that you lock a row in staff before the insert statement:

```
select id from staff where id = p_staff_id for update;
```

That way the lock affects only one staff member (provided you have row level locks).

Comment: Would this prevent an entry from being inserted into the JOBS table if you lock the STAFF table?

Comment: It would prevent the second transaction from locking the same row, so as long as all inserts use the same procedure (or at least locks the same row) it will work.

Comment: It would require the use of the insert procedure though. If there were inserts into the JOBS table from any other source then the original problem could still arise.

Comment: Klas: Would this work if there are currently no entries for the staff member, and we simultaneously insert two? Wouldn't in this case the select lock no rows? And if so, do you have a solution that will also work if the staff member has no jobs and then gets two inserted at the same time?

Comment: The number of jobs held by the staffer is irrelevant as long as the staffer exists in the staff table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a database [trigger](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) to enforce the singularity of staff jobs.

If an overlapping job for an individual staff member is found then it would not allow the insert and you therefore could not get overlapping jobs.

In the case your question specifies, whichever job was committed second would fail due to the trigger checking the inserts.

BTW, locking the ENTIRE table would not be a good solution. Also, trying to use `SELECT` `FOR UPDATE` would not prevent two inserts.

Comment: Make sure the trigger is `ON COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Onw way you could consider is using materialized views with check constraints.  See [this old blog post of mine](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html) where there is an example "1) Rule: An employee cannot have overlapping project assignments" very similar to yours.

Caution: maintaining materialized views has performance implications, so don't implement without proper performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the jobs are allocated in rounded fairly large blocks of time, 1 hour or 30 minutes (1/24/60*30)

You could create a new table booked_time_slot with a primay key on staff_id & time 
(or the date & slot number)

If you insert a row for each time slot used:
(the example below gets each 30 minute slot between the start and end time and stores it)

```
INSERT INTO booked_time_slot
  SELECT p_staff_id,TO_DATE('2011/08/21 11:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24/MI/SS') + 
      ((ROWNUM-1)*(1/24/60*30))  
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY TO_DATE('2011/08/21 11:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24/MI/SS') + 
      ((ROWNUM-1)*(1/24/60*30)) <  
          TO_DATE('2011/08/21 12:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24/MI/SS')
```

The Primary key will stop any duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

if the staff_id should be unique, you should generate it by sequence.

and when you do the inserting, you just do it this way:

```
insert into jobs 
(
    select seq_staff_id.nextval, p_job_name, p_start_date, p_end_date from dual 
)
```

Comment: Will Wu: The staff_id should not be unique. One staff member could have multiple jobs to complete. That's the whole point, list a staff members jobs and ensure no clashes for that staff member.

Comment: Please ignore this answer.the issue caused by that you have not specify end_date for each add_job.

Comment: you select 1 from jobs 
      where staff_id = p_staff_id
        and 
        (  
            (end_date > p_start_date  and start_date < p_start_date) 
            or 
            (end_date > p_end_date) and (start_date < p_end_date)
        )'

Comment: @Clinton: you need to add more judgement as following, there are nothing to do with table lock.

select 1 from jobs 
      where staff_id = p_staff_id
        and 
        (  
            (end_date > p_start_date  and start_date < p_start_date) 
            or 
            (end_date > p_end_date) and (start_date < p_end_date)
        )

Comment: I don't think this answers my question.